Ffmpeg image quality/resolution to 64 bit depth and 32 bit float
How do I change ffmpeg image quality/resolution to 64 bit depth and 32 bit float? I’m still trying to make it the best quality PNG image possible.
I’m using this format:
ffmpeg -lavfi "color=black:4090x2160, drawtext=text='Example' :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :fontfile:Arial.ttf :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" -frames 1 out.png


I apologize I meant where should I include 64 bit depth with 32 bit float in the command above?

If you need to clarify your question you should [edit] it and be sure to properly format it.

64 bit is 4 x 16 bits per channel. The fourth channel being an alpha channel. There is no transparency in your command, therefore 48 bit should suffice.Though for white on black, this is probably overkill. Also, I was not aware that PNG supports floating point, what inclines you to think otherwise.

I thought it would work for ffmpeg because in GIMP there is an option 32 bit float for png.

From previous discussions I remember, I believe Gimp can process 32 bit floating point, but it cannot be saved to the PNG format, There are formats that support this, but I couldn't personally advise. Probably worth googling for more clarity.

Also, try adding -pix_fmt rgba64 to the end of your script, if you require an alpha channel. If no alpha channel is required, try -pix_fmt rgb48.

Question I know 32 bit float would be overkill for png, what’s the command btw? Just wondering I know it probably won’t be compatible to png but want to know how to write it and add it to other image format?

Sorry, never had a need to use floating point. Would not like to advise, I suspect it depends on the output format. Also, I cannot ever remember coming across any info for this with ffmpeg, maybe there is a reason for that?

It’s ok, I figured it out, you can close question now

No, the question should not be closed. You can post a solution, even to your own question. This will help others in the future. That's the purpose of SU.
